# Gradient background color with UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uiscrollviewdelegate, cagradientlayer

I know this question might look like a duplicate, however most answers disregard the fact of scrolling in the view.

When I scroll the gradient color stays constant through the whole scroll , and not entirely for the background. For example the height of the view is 1500, and the current view where i'm looking is (example) 450, then in this 450 the gradient is constant throughout the other 1050 instead of while scrolling it should get darker and darker (to the other color). Here is an image for better understanding

https://ibb.co/euKcLd

https://ibb.co/bHNxLd

https://ibb.co/eZgA6J

And this is the code I am using:

```
func setGradientColour() {
        let colorTop =  UIColor(red: 255.0/255.0, green: 149.0/255.0, blue: 0.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
        let colorBottom = UIColor(red: 255.0/255.0, green: 0/255.0, blue: 0/255.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.colors = [colorTop, colorBottom]
        gradientLayer.locations = [0.0, 1.0]
        gradientLayer.frame = self.view.bounds
        self.view.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
    }
```

Which is being called in the viewDidLoad method.

Comment: are you using scrollView?

Comment: @Shezad Yes. You can see it in the second photo link.

Comment: So try applying the gradient to scrollView not to your view

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the code was wrong and must be changed to:

```
func setGradientColour() {
    let colorTop =  UIColor(red: 255.0/255.0, green: 149.0/255.0, blue: 0.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
    let colorBottom = UIColor(red: 255.0/255.0, green: 0/255.0, blue: 0/255.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer.colors = [colorTop, colorBottom]
    gradientLayer.locations = [0.0, 1.0]
    gradientLayer.frame = scrollViewTest.bounds
    scrollViewTest.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
}
```

Where scrollViewTest is the outlet for the scrollView. The mistake was that I was calling the normal view layer instead of the scrollview which reduced the length of view.